# Is there an "-onym" for "group names of animals?"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Psuedonyms are false names.

Synonyms are similar names

Antonyms are opposite names.

There are also aptronyms, homonymns, eponyms, demonyms, and retronyms.

Is there an "-onym" that applies to groups of animals? (Not sure, but maybe my question is really "is there an -onymn for a collective group of animals or collective groups of anything?)

Comment: The term that is common is "collective noun" see the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun#Terms_of_venery) or [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_terms_of_venery,_by_animal) for examples.

This doesn't end in -onym unfortunately

Comment: If there were a word for species ending in -onym, it would be phylonym..  Sadly, it would apply to all living species, including plants.  Equally unfortunately, it does not exist:  not, at least in Webster.  There is a good reason for this.  ‘Species name’ is short and can read be understood by everyone.  So why introduce a special word that many have to stop and look up?

Comment: I suppose *terms of venery* has sufficed. And *cladonym* is specific to an actual clade, not a flock or herd.